# Asymptotics to Taylor expansions?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, inequalities, asymptotics, nonlinear-optimization, taylor-series

I posted a question on MSE about approximating Taylor series but Despite a bounty I did not receive any answers or comments.

Maybe you guys can help.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440931/proof-that-oint-r-dx-n-n-0

Let $f(x)$ be a real-entire function such that for all $x>0$ we have
$f(x) > 0$, $f'(x) > 0$ , $f '' (x) > 0$.

And also $0 < D^M f(0) < D^{M-1} f(0)$.

Let $0<T<1$ and $n$ a positive integer.

Let $g(x,n) = \frac{f(x)}{x^n}$.

Let real $x_0(n)$ satisfy
$x_0 (n)> 0$

$g ' (x_0(n),n) = 0$

Let $r(n)$ be a contour that contains the real interval $[T,x_0(n) + T]$ but not $0$ , not a negative number and no poles or zeros off the real line.

> **Conjecture A:** there is Always an integer $N$ (depending on $f$) such that for all $n > N$
> $$ \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \oint_{r(n)} (x-T)^{n-1} f(x+T) - \sqrt n \ln(e+n)  g(x,n) \frac{g '' (x,n) }{g ' (x,n) } < 0. $$

A similar conjecture that is probably not compatible with Conjecture A (they probably cannot both be true, but I believe at least one is true).

> **Conjecture B:** there is Always an integer $N$ (depending on $f$) such that for all $n > N$ there exists a positive $w$ independent of $n$ such that
> $$ \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \oint_{r(n)} (x-T)^{n-1} f(x+T) -  \frac{w g(x,n) g '' (x,n) \sqrt { f '' (x)} }{g ' (x,n) } < 0. $$

(the derivatives are with respect to $x$ , not $n$)

How to prove/disprove them ?

In case these contour integrals look random/confusing notice that

$$ \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \oint_{r(n)} (x-T)^{n-1} f(x+T) $$

Is just the sequence of Taylor coefficients for $f(x)$.

Also

$$ \frac {1} {2 \pi i} \oint_{r(n)}  g(x,n) \frac{g '' (x,n) }{g ' (x,n) }$$

Is simply minimum($f(x)/x^n $) for $x > 1.$

So basically we want to understand how good the intuitive estimate min($f(x)/x^n $)  is compared to $D^n f(x) / n! $.

EDIT

Maybe this helps ??

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiman-Valiron_theory

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Comment: It would be best to copy the question (mentioning it is a copy) instead of providing a link.

Comment: @Chris Ramsey : Done.

Comment: Maybe this helps ?? Should I add it to the question ?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiman-Valiron_theory